# Enter missing date-times into specific cells of a data.frame (R)

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, strptime

I have a big data.frame and located some missing values respectively there are some wrong formats which I guess that `strptime` isn't able to detect:

```
D = data.frame(a = c("2007-06-22","2007-05-22","3032016"), b = c("2007-06-23","2007-06-24", "2007-06-25"))
           a          b
1 2007-06-22 2007-06-23
2 2007-05-22 2007-06-24
3    3032016 2007-06-25
```

How can I input a specific date-format into that cell? Something like:

```
D[3,1] <- "2016-03-30"
```

Edit: This question is indepdent of the initial format. Even for a set of:

```
           a          b
1 2007-06-22 2007-06-23
2 2007-05-22 2007-06-24
3        123 2007-06-25
```

or

```
           a          b
1 2007-06-22 2007-06-23
2 2007-05-22 2007-06-24
3         NA 2007-06-25
```

I would like to enter some new date-time data. It might be an easy question, nonetheless, I am not aware of the correct command.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see how my questions is a duplicate. There is no format description which fits my given data, i.d. I don't  have a symbol of separation on 3032016. How can I apply it?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is just updating `D[3,1]`?  it could be a problem with the dataframe defining the columns as factors instead of characters  If it were characters your command would work.

Comment: Try `D$a <- as.character(D$a)` or add the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option to your `data.frame()` command, then  D[3,1] <- "2016-03-30"` and your assignment will work as I think you expect.

Comment: Maybe improve the question by posting the error you get by typing the `D[3,1] <- "2016-03-30"` command & what you wanted to happen.